# pandas how to find the number of rows with the values of a column equal space

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering how to find the number of rows in a `df` when the values of a column equal to one or more space or tab or newline,

```
df['currency'].str.findall(r'[^\s|\n|\t]+')
```

but the above code only gave me the row indices on values on `currency` column.

Comment: `|` in a character class `[]` matches the character literally. Also, `\s` includes both `\n` and `\t`. Fixing all this leaves you with `[^\s]`, which is the same as using `\S`

Comment: Just use `\s+` since you're trying to match one or more whitespace characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.str.contains`, which will return a boolean value for each row, and then summing the result:

```
df['currency'].str.contains(r'\S+').sum()
```

Updated regex based on tips from @Jan and @ctwheels -- `\s+` will match one or more whitespace character (`\S` will match one or more non-whitespace character, if that's what you need instead).

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for

```
df['currency'].str.contains(r'\s+').sum()
```

Your current approach looks for line that **do not** contain whitespaces.
Additionally, `\s` already includes `\n` and `\t`, so there's no need for a character class here, really. The `+` operator matches one or more times.

---

For the records, `\s` is equivalent to

```
[ \t\n\r\f\v]
```

See the [**Python documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) for more details.

Comment: Yep it's this simple.

Comment: how to also find the empty string in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex for this. One way is to apply [`pd.Series.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and test whether your result is an empty string.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['  ', '\t', ' ', 'string', '--'])

res = s.str.strip().values == ''

# array([ True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

To count the number of rows:

```
res = (s.str.strip().values == '').sum()
```